# Python newbie having a problem using classes

Tags: python, class

Im just beginning to mess around a bit with classes; however, I am running across a problem.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
print MyClass.f
```

The previous script is returning `<unbound method MyClass.f>` instead of the intended value. How do I fix this?

Comment: What tutorial are you reading?  Where did you see code like this?

Comment: I was reading from a textbook, however, it was pretty vague about the code and didn't provide a simple example. So I just fiddled around and tried to get something to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MyClass.f` refers to the function object f which is a property of MyClass. In your case, f is an instance method (has a self parameter) so its called on a particular instance. Its "unbound" because you're referring to f without specifying a specific class, kind of like referring to a steering wheel without a car.

You can create an instance of MyClass and call f from it like so:

```
x = MyClass()
x.f()
```

(This specifies which instance to call f from, so you can refer to instance variables and the like.)

You're using f as a `static method`. These methods aren't bound to a particular class, and can only reference their parameters.

A static method would be created and used like so:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def f():                 #no self parameter
        return 'hello world'
print MyClass.f()
```

Answer (score 6):

Create an instance of your class: `m = MyClass()`

then use `m.f()` to call the function

Now you may wonder why you don't have to pass a parameter to the function (the 'self' param). It is because the instance on which you call the function is actually passed as the first parameter.

That is, `MyClass.f(m)` equals `m.f()`, where `m` is an instance object of class `MyClass`.

Good luck!