# Unbound method in Python

Tags: python, class

In [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) link while explaining classes, for the following sample class

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

it is mentioned that

> then `MyClass.i` and `MyClass.f` are valid attribute references, returning an integer and a function object, respectively

but when I try to `print MyClass.f` it gives me a error `<unbound method MyClass.f>`.

So what does `MyClass.f` returning function object really mean in this context.

Comment: That's not an error, that's **the representation of the function object** (strictly, per the description, a method object).

Comment: So shouldn't it print "Hello world"?

Comment: You need to call it. MyClass.f()

Comment: *"So shouldn't it print "Hello world"?"* - no, that's what the method **does**. If you want to call it, you need to instantiate an instance of `MyClass` and call the method: `MyClass().f()` (note parentheses).

Comment: It's an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232740/python-newbie-having-a-problem-using-classes

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not really, it was 1st hit for me when I put `<unbound method MyClass.f>` in google =). Anyways, good  that you have power to mark it right away, teamwork FTW.

Comment: @luk32 all hail [the mighty Mjölnir](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/248731)

Comment: This is not an error but a warning. If you were using Python 3.8 you won't have any problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that the method isn't bound to any instance.
If you did this:

```
myinstance = MyClass()
myinstance.f() # "hello world"
```

It would work, or, you can make it static:

```
class MyClass
    @staticmethod
    def f()
        print "hello world"

MyClass.f()
```

Would also work

Answer (score 0):

Instance it:

```
>>> your_class = MyClass()
>>> your_class.f()
'hello world'
```

It's bound when you instance it:

```
>>> your_class.f
<bound method MyClass.f of <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x1244ef0>>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is an instance method. You should use classmethod or staticmethod, like this:

```
>>> class A():
...    @staticmethod
...    def f(*args):
...      return "hello"
... 
>>> A.f
<function f at 0xb744541c>
>>> print A.f
<function f at 0xb744541c>
>>> print A.f()
hello
```