# Python telnet connection failure

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, telnet

I have device that accepts telnet connection to use it with AT commands

This is my code, should be simple I believe but it won't work for some reason I'm fairly new to telnet lib so I don't understand what I am missing here

```
def connect(self, host, port):
    try:
        Telnet.open(host, port)
        Telnet.write('AT'+"\r")
        if Telnet.read_until("OK"):
            print("You are connected")
    except:
        print("Connection cannot be established")
```

it always hits the except.

I am also getting the following error when I just try and import telnetlib and run it just with an IP with no port.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
Telnet.open('192.168.0.1')
TypeError: unbound method open() must be called with Telnet instance as 
first argument (got str instance instead)
```

I am having problems understanding what does it want me to do.

Comment: The error is clear, it is necessary that you indicate the port.

Comment: Shouldn't the port default to 23?

Comment: telnet = Telnet() , telnet.open(host, port) . Its evident from the error that open is not a static method

Comment: I think I see. Both problems stem from `Telnet.open(...)`. You need to make an instance first, then call `open` and `write` on the instance. See answer by lungj

Comment: @eyllanesc What quamrana said: [the port number defaults to the standard Telnet port (23)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.open). But it's better to avoid using the `.open` method, and just use the `telnetlib.Telnet` constructor to open the connection.

Comment: Which Python version are you actually using? If you're using Python 3.6 (or later) you can open the connection in a `with` statement, as shown in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet).

Comment: Yes i am aware but with will auto close the connection when the statement is done, i do not want to close the connectiong

Comment: `with` will auto close the connection when you exit the `with` block. So you just need to put all your interactions with the connection inside that `with` block. Of course if you don't want that extra level of indentation you're perfectly free to do it the old way, with an explicit `.close()` call. OTOH, using `with` is preferred because it guarantees that the connection will be closed, no matter what happens.

Comment: I understand thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor for the `Telnet` class needs to be called:

```
import traceback

def connect(self, host, port):
    try:
        telnet_obj = Telnet(host, port) # Use the constructor instead of the open() method.
    except Exception as e: # Should explicitly list exceptions to be caught. Also, only include the minimum code where you can handle the error.
        print("Connection cannot be established")
        traceback.print_exc() # Get a traceback of the error.
        # Do further error handling here and return/reraise.

    # This code is unrelated to opening a connection, so your error
    # handler for establishing a connection should not be run if
    # write() or read_until() raise an error.
    telnet_obj.write('AT'+"\r") # then use the returned object's methods.
    if telnet_obj.read_until("OK"):
        print("You are connected")
```

Related: [Python newbie having a problem using classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232740/python-newbie-having-a-problem-using-classes)

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a bare `except` clause. Explicitly name the exception(s) you want to catch!

Comment: @PM2Ring true; I just modified the code from OP to address the issue being faced. I'll at least slightly improve the code in an edit.

Comment: @lungj I see your answer fixes the problem that the OP has reported. Well Done.

Comment: yes i am aware i need to except a more explicit errors, im just trying to get a handle how it works, eventually i will add them.

Comment: Fair enough. AFAICT, the main possible exceptions (not counting SyntaxError ;)) are `ConnectionRefusedError` [Errno 111], and `socket.gaierror` [Errno -2] Name or service not known.

Comment: Im using the code that @lungj wrote and i am still getting an error "local variable 'telnet_obj' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Did you see "Connection cannot be established"? If there was a connection error, `telnet_obj` will not be defined and you'll get that particular error. As such, you must return from the function or reraise the exception if you encounter a connection error.

Comment: yes i do see the error message " Connection cannot be established" , i think i know maybe why.

Comment: @Mike.G lungj 's code isn't a complete solution: it _ignores_ errors. You can put a `raise` statement after the `print("Connection cannot be established")` so that the code will abort (with an error message) after it executes that `print` call. But if you're getting that "Connection cannot be established" message, you need to verify that the host string & port number are correct.

Comment: What @PM2Ring said :) Also, I've slightly updated the answer to print an exception trace to help with your troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you very much for that @lungj, but not getting the traceback, getting an error, sorry missed the import traceback

Comment: Now i am getting "You are connected", now to figure out how to send the AT commands the right way and to read them back properly, thank you for the help guys